# Programmatically creating a UIScrollView inside of a UITableViewCell - ScrollView doesn't scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am attempting to create a dynamically generated `UIScrollView` within a `UITableView Cell`. The `UIScrollView` is built using a `build function` within the `ScrollViewClass`. The class takes an array of views and positions them side by side, then returns a `ScrollView` which can then be added to the `cell's subviews`. The `ScrollView` is added and visible, however, the `ScrollView` does not scroll horizontally as intended. All of the code for this can be found below.

**ScrollViewClass**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ScrollViewClass {
    let ArrayOfViews: [UIView]
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()

    init(ArrayOfViews: [UIView]) {
        self.ArrayOfViews = ArrayOfViews
    }

    func build() -> UIScrollView {
        scrollView.isScrollEnabled =  true
        scrollView.frame.size.width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        scrollView.frame.size.height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 2000, height: 500)
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = true

        for (index, views) in ArrayOfViews.enumerated() {
            scrollView.addSubview(views)
            views.frame.origin.x = CGFloat(index) * UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2
            print(index)
        }

        return scrollView
    }
}
```

**TableView CellForRowAt**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: UITableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellID")
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none;

        let view1 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 500))
        let view2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 500))
        let view3 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 500))

        view1.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        view2.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        view3.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        let ArrayOfViews = [view1, view2, view3]
        let scrollView = ScrollViewClass(ArrayOfViews: ArrayOfViews)
        cell.addSubview(scrollView.build())

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: You are setting `scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`, but you are not giving it any constraints. Try `scrollView.backgroundColor = .red` and I'm guessing you won't see any red - but you can see its subviews because `.clipsToBounds` is not set to true.

Comment: @DonMag I will fix this! However, this still doesn't fix the scrolling issue

Comment: As a side note, if you are adding a scrollView every time `cellForRowAt` is called, you will be adding it multiple times (cells are reused).

Comment: Did you check to see if it fixes the scrolling issue?

Comment: @DonMag Sorry, how would I go about doing this, I'm fairly new to xcode. But it does make sense as if the view is only disabled due to the clipping then the touch detection isn't there

Comment: Actually, I just tried your code, and... while you are doing a bunch of things wrong, I *do* get horizontal scrolling in the cell(s). Is there some other code you are using that may be interfering with it?

Comment: @DonMag not that I can think of, im going have to go comment a lot of stuff out to find the problem. But thank you for verifying it works and sorry my stuff is wrong as you can tell I'm fairly new to swift

Answer (score 0):

You should use UIStackView with horizontal axis so the scrollview can get the contentSize properly.

**ScrollViewClass**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ScrollViewClass {
    let ArrayOfViews: [UIView]
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()

    init(ArrayOfViews: [UIView]) {
        self.ArrayOfViews = ArrayOfViews
    }

    func build() -> UIScrollView {
        scrollView.isScrollEnabled =  true
        scrollView.frame.size.width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        scrollView.frame.size.height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 2000, height: 500)
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = true
        let stackView:UIStackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .horizontal
        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        stackView.alignment = .fill
        stackView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

        for (index, views) in ArrayOfViews.enumerated() {
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(views)
            print(index)
        }
        scrollView.addSubview(stackView)  
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true 
        stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true  
        return scrollView
    }
}
```

You should also give constraints to the `scrollView` in the `cellForRowAt:`

```
    let scrollView = ScrollViewClass(ArrayOfViews: ArrayOfViews)
    cell.addSubview(scrollView.build())
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true 
    scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

Comment: When running your coding, it through an error with the spacing. Also it doesn't display the views in the table.

Comment: Please try it now.

Comment: The error has gone however, the view still isn't being displayed

Comment: try it again now.

Comment: Sadly still not displaying, I printed the views within the for loop to check if they are being pull through and they are, so something to do with the stactview

Comment: I removed the, distribution, alignment, autoresizingMask and constraints, adding a frame height and width. Then the view is displayed within the table. However still have the same problem where the scrollView wont scroll

Comment: try it now, I have added constraints to the scrollView and updated constraints of stackView.

Comment: After a lot of rebuilding, I managed to get the scrolling working with my original code. However, you have pointed out a better solution to my design yet when implementing your code it makes all of the views sit on top of each other

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168669/discussion-between-hardik-parmar-and-matt-hammond).